# How to show image in fragment ImageView from firebase storage

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, firebase-storage, android-viewmodel

I wanted to know is there a way i can show my image view image in fragment.
The image i am getting is from Firebase storage and passing the bitmap value through a view Model function and including the value in the fragment.

I wanted to know is there a better way to do this?

Also when there is no image, the image still shows when i pair it up with androidswipetorefresh listener

**Main Activity Code**

```
val imageName = auth.currentUser?.uid
val storageRef = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().reference.child("profileImages/$imageName.jpg")

    val localFile = File.createTempFile("tempImage","jpg")
    storageRef.getFile(localFile).addOnSuccessListener {
        val bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(localFile.absolutePath)
        fragmentViewModel.setImage(bitmap)
    }.addOnFailureListener {
        Toast.makeText(this,"Failed",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
    }
```

**Fragment Code**

```
profileImg = view.findViewById(R.id.profileImage)

    val bitmap = viewModel.imageData.value
    profileImg.setImageBitmap(bitmap)
```

**View Model Code**

```
val imageData = MutableLiveData<Bitmap>() fun setImage (newData: Bitmap) {
    imageData.value = newData
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When getting images from a specific URL, it's more likely to be used a third-party library that can do the job for you. So, I definitely recommend you to use an image **loading** and **caching** library. For Android we have [Glide](https://github.com/bumptech/glide):

> Glide is a fast and efficient open-source media management and image loading framework for Android that wraps media decoding, memory and **disk caching**, and resource pooling into a simple and easy-to-use interface.